# Cannot add right bar button in navigation bar in storyboards iOS8

Tags: ios, storyboard

As the title suggests, I would like to know if it is possible to avoid adding right bar button in the navigation bar through code.

I've done the usual process with a view controller embedded in a navigation controller and trying to drop the bar button item inside the navigation bar of the view controller, but it no longer works for some reasons.

So is it possible to be done in the storyboard somehow in iOS 8?

Xcode ver. 6.2 Stable

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Well, it seems there is a problem with the differences between new segues introduced in iOS 8 and the old ones. In this case it is the difference between `push` segues which allows adding a right bar button in storyboard and `show` segue which if added automatically (dragging from a controller to another) does not allow dropping the button in the navigation bar.

The reason is when using the *old* segues, the controller would automatically be given a navigation bar, thus you can add elements to it, while if using the *new* segues the navigation bar is not automatically added to the controller in the storyboard.

What solved this issue for me was:

1. Selecting the segue which leads to the problematic controller
2. Changing it to the "deprecated" `push` segue
3. Changing it back to the accepted `show` segue

Result: Now I can add as always the right bar button item through Storyboard.

Comment: Who would have thought it is actually a bug in Xcode!! Thanks a lot! BTW.. my project is also in Swift, and i'm using iOS 8 too.

Comment: Tx for pointing this bug out: I am using Xcode 7.0.1 and the bug is still there!

Comment: Easiest way solved my problem. I'm using Xcode 7.1. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks, wish I would have seen this last November ... started a new contract and was shunned because I mentioned I couldn't add a right bar button. thanks Xcode IB (7.2.1). What are we going to do when the push goes away.... not be allowed to add bar button items?

Comment: @MatthewFerguson, you'll have to add the navigation item to the controller :) which at the moment is added automatically with old push segues.

Comment: @Fawkes , are you talking about the UINavigationController or the UIViewController attach to the storyboard?  Programmatically or through IB?

Comment: @MatthewFerguson, in your object library (from where you can drag graphical elements: UIView, UILabel, UIButton, etc.) type in the filter box "UINavigationItem" and you'll see the element I'm referring. If you drop this element in a controller where you had the problem specified in this article, you'll be able to again, drag and drop elements on to the navigation bar. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fawkes  Yes. makes sense now.  I was adding "UIBarButtonItem" and in the past the top navigation bar accepted it.  With the new segue you need to add the UINavigationItem as you stated.  By the way, the UIBarButtonItem goes to the bottom tab bar on new segues.  I had a bad habit that I expected to be available forever.

Comment: That works! Another stupid bug from apple. I started to develop ios apps after android. Ios is very limited and full of silly bugs

Comment: Thanks a lot! How you are able to figure it out?

Comment: @Alex If I'm not wrong it all started from the comparison with an old controller in another storyboard I had on which I was able to drop the UIBarButtonItem. Then it was just a job of comparison between the two.

Comment: Amazing! It's 2019 Xcode 10.1 IOS 12. This bug still exists, and you have the solution.

Comment: @Dohab to be fair, I'm not sure if it's a bug :) it can be as well that it was intended for some unknown reasons. Like make developers aware that they need a uinavigationbar object on which to drop things. The old implementation was doing that automatically so developers were not really understanding what was there under the hood. But this is just a "conspiracy" theory of mine :)

Comment: @Fawkes Xcode storyboard has some other faults too. Sometimes, when I roll the mouse up and down, the view starts to shift itself to the right a little bit. I faced it in three different MACs. Also, switching between drop down elements to fix something is a PC thing, due to many reasons (buffer, compatibility .. etc), but not in OSX.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to add BarButtonItem to not RootViewController you must first add Navigation Item to your ViewController.

Comment: I was trying to add to root.. XD XD

Answer (score 6):

First select a UIBarButtonItem from the object library. Then drag into the right corner of the navigationBar.

[image: UIBarButtonItem]
[image: Navigation bar]

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this, and I cannot drop it there. I guess there are some settings regarding the navigation bar. I tried to set show the navigation bar on the Navigation Controller in the storyboards, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does your UIViewController looks like the one in the image?

Comment: You will need to embed your UIViewController in a navigation controller. Will add an image to show how.

Comment: It is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: the only thing it does when I try to drop it inside the navigation bar, is creating a bottom bar with the button I try to drop.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your storyboard please? It usually inserts it automatically in a toolbar if your viewcontroller isn't stacked in a uinavigationcontroller.

Comment: look at my answer... It is also confusing for me.. but I tried it 3 times in both storyboards I have and the "bug" repeats itself in all the cases with navigation controllers embedding my view controllers.

Comment: OP already indicated that trying to drop the button into the bar doesn't work, so this does not address the issue.

Comment: Did you get the solution for the above problem ? @rcat24

Comment: @RamcharanReddy try the approved answer

Comment: in a navigation controller for the viewcontroller i can't create a rightbar button. this is my issue. approved answer is helpless in my case. @rcat24

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

**Try changing your Views simulated size to Freeform.** The property is found under Size Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Another case in which I had problems adding a bar item to the top bar is if a Navigation Controller seques to a Tab Bar Controller. In that case you have to add the bar items to the TabV Bar Controller Navigation Item, not the individual View Controllers that are attached to the Tab Bar Controller.